# Check if user exists before creating new user - Firebase Auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have firebase auth where there is an allowance for anonymous logins. When the user arrives at the homepage, we check if this newly created user.uid exists in firebase auth. If not it then creates a new user with that uid.

```
firebase.database().ref()
.child('users')
.child(user.user.uid)
.once('value', snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.val() === null) {
        firebase
            .database()
            .ref()
            .child(`user/${user.user.uid}/info`)
            .set({
                uid: user.user.uid
            })
            .then(() => user)
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }
})
```

However, I keep getting this error: Seems the application is not allowed to check for existing aid in firebase.auth

```
Error: permission_denied at /users/ONOfaUBN88gMpG9iVJU1dLvVvbN2: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
```

How best can I rework this? I had now included the snapshot check because I was also getting a similar error message from firebase which basically said that user already exists and cannot be reset.

I had the rules set as :

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
    }
}
```

would these serve my purpose now:

```
{
  "rules": {
      "users": {
        "$uid": {
          ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
          ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you'll have an easier time with this if you just protect the user's location in the database with security rules, so you can be certain that only the user with their given ID can write the location that matches that ID.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security

Comment: I think this could be the basis of a good answer Doug. :)

Comment: Thanks guys. I have added a rules portion to my question. It still gives a warning though, perhaps that's how it goes?